# $H^0$-stability and slope-stability

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

**Definition:** $E$ is called **$H^0$-semistable** if for all line bundles $L\subset E$ we have
$$
h^0(L) \leq \frac{h^0(E)}{2}
$$
$E$ is called **slope-semistable** if for all subbundles we have
$$ 
\frac{\deg L}{\operatorname{rk} L} \leq \frac{\deg E}{\operatorname{rk} E},
$$
i.e. here, because $E$ has rank two
$$
\deg L \leq \frac{\deg E}{2}.

Why is $E$, a vector bundle of rank $2$ over a curve $C$,  $H^0$-semistable if and only if $E$ is slope-semistable?

The direction slope-semistable implies $H^0$-semistable seems to work by manipulating Riemann-Roch well enough, but I cannot get the other direction to work.

Comment: I think you can tensor $E$ by an ample line bundle to assume that $H^1(E)=0$. This doesn't change stability. Then everything is just Riemann-Roch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. By your definition any rank 2 vector bundle $E$ with $H^0(E) = 0$ is $H^0$-semistable; in particular a sufficiently negative twist of any rank 2 vector bundle is $H^0$-semistable. However, slope stability is invariant under any twists, so if you take you favorite slope-unstable bundle and take its sufficiently negative twist, this will be a counterexample.

Comment: Okay, I guess when $E$ has no $H^1$, the $H^0$-semistability does imply slope-semistability. Perhaps, this is because the condition $h^0(L)\le h^0(E)/2$ is not well behaved under the operation by tensoring a line bundle.